# reading comma-separated strings with read.csv()

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to load a comma-delimited data file that also has commas in one of its text columns. The following sample code generates such a file`'test.csv',`which I'll load using`read.csv()`to illustrate my problem.

```
> d <- data.frame(name = c("John Smith", "Smith, John"), age = c(34, 34))
> d
         name age
1  John Smith  34
2 Smith, John  34
> write.csv(d, file = "test.csv", quote = F, row.names = F)
> d2 <- read.csv("test.csv")
> d2
            name age
John Smith    34  NA
Smith       John  34
```

Because of the `','` in `Smith, John`, `d2` is not assigned correctly. How do I read the file so that `d2` looks exactly like `d`?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you wrote the file with `quote=F`.  Just take that away and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is the file was sent to me as-is. I used this sample code to create such a file.

Comment: @Manojit You need to _escape_ the CSV entries in the file, because some of you data itself has commas in it.  Without quotes, `read.csv` will see this in the second line: `Smith, John, 34` ... i.e. it will see _three_ columns.

Comment: @Manojit Is it just the one column that has commas, or are there multiple columns that have this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks. Unfortunately, as I explained before, I did not write the file myself, it was sent to me as is (the`write.csv()`bit is to generate an example file to illustrate my problem). I guess there is no easy way to do this with`read.csv()`or`read.table(),`I may have to edit it using something like Excel.

Comment: @G5W only one column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) read.pattern** `read.pattern` (in gsubfn package) can read such files:

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "(.*),(.*)"
read.pattern("test.csv", pattern = pat, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
         name age
1  John Smith  34
2 Smith, John  34
```

**2) two pass**  Another possibility is to read it in, fix it up and then re-read it.  This uses no packages and gives the same output.

```
L <- readLines("test.csv")
read.table(text = sub("(.*),", "\\1|", L), header = TRUE, sep = "|", as.is = TRUE)
```

**Note:** For 3 fields with the third field at the end use this in (1)

```
pat <- "(.*),([^,]+),([^,]+)"
```

The same situation use this in (2) assuming that there are non-spaces adjacent to each of the last two commas and at least one space adjacent to any commas in the text field and that fields have at least 2 characters:

```
text = gsub("(\\S),(\\S)", "\\1|\\2", L)
```

If you have some other arrangement just modify the regular expression in (1) appropriately and the `sub` or `gsub` in (2).

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem with`test.csv.`My actual file has another numerical column before the text column. How should I adapt the`read.table()`syntax for that file?

Comment: Have moved comment to Note at end of answer.

Comment: Thanks!`pat <- "([^,]+),(.*),(.*)"`works with the file that has columns in order "numerical", "text", "numerical". How do I use your method #2 with this file?

Comment: Ok - you already answered it while I was typing my previous comment. Thanks again!

Comment: Your answer worked almost perfectly. Unfortunately few of the names in my data file have apostrophes in them (for example, "Smith, John's niece"). The`sub/gsub`syntax somehow merges all data in between two such apostrophes as a single data. Is there a way to include those in`sub/gsub`?

Comment: use `quote = ""` in `read.pattern` and `read.table` to disable quotes.